# in c++ asio how create same socket object for http or https (interface / abstract problem ?)

Tags: c++, oop, boost-asio, asio

I have a console program myprog.exe using 1 parameter

if my parameter has http substring (ex: `myprog.exe "http://127.0.0.1/myservice"`) my program should connect on **http**

if my parameter has https substring (ex: `myprog.exe "https://127.0.0.1/myservice"`) my program should connect on **https**

i use asio https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio

if I use http I create socket using:

```
tcp::socket socket(io_context);
connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
...
asio::write(socket, request);
```

if I use https I create socket using:

```
asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_ssl(io_context, ctx);
asio::connect(socket_ssl.lowest_layer(), resolver.resolve(resolver_query));
...
asio::write(socket_ssl, request);
```

I would like to use only 1 socket object creation to avoid write same asio::write for http or https and simplify my code. Something like this:

```
bool bIsHttps = true 
my_abstract_socket declaration ????
if (bIsHttps) {
  my_abstract_socket = createsocket("https")
} else {
  my_abstract_socket = createsocket("http")
}    
asio::write(my_abstract_socket, request);
```

Is this problem can be resolved with abstract/interface or other solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool bIsHttps = Is_ssl(argv[1]);
tcp::socket socket* my_abstract_socket = NULL;
if (bIsHttps) {
  my_abstract_socket = new asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(io_context, ctx);
} else {
  my_abstract_socket = new tcp::socket socket(io_context);
}    
asio::write(*my_abstract_socket, request);
```

Comment: That seems to do not work . My visual studio indicate `cannot convert from 'asio::ssl::stream<Stream> *' to 'asio::ip::tcp::socket *'`

Comment: @fr3948, exact, I was wrong (quick and dirty symptom). Anyway you have two options:  
    1- Continue that way by inheriting from a pure virtual template class, declaring pure member functions. :-(  
    2- Use the [Boost.Beast library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html) and his [WebSocket](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket.html) class. :-)

Comment: These solutions are too complex for me. Asio is already very difficult to understand but there is not so much http class which work with my visual studio 2012. I will work on a better solution than 2 different sockets when I will be a better coder :)

Comment: @fr3948 Programming, network programming, concurrency programming is complex and very difficult. But C++, asio, Boost.Beast helps a lot.  
Anyway, welcome in stackoveflow !